# After ends method doPost() runs method doGet() without calling this method in StartServlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I want to validate information about user. If user has been entered and trying enter to `/login` page, forward to userpage.

As of this moment i have this:

**StartServlet**

```
public class StartServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        UserDTO userDTO = (UserDTO) req.getSession().getAttribute("userDTO");
        if (userDTO == null) {
            req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getContextPath() + "/WEB-INF/pages/login.jspx").forward(req, resp);
        } else {
            req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getContextPath() + "/checklogin").forward(req, resp);
        }
    }
}
```

ValidateServlet

```
public class ValidateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        UserDTO userDTO = (UserDTO) req.getSession().getAttribute("userDTO");

        if (userDTO == null) {
            userDTO = UserService.getInstance().validateUserDTO(email, password);
        }

        if (userDTO != null) {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("userDTO", userDTO);
            if (userDTO.getRole() == Role.ADMINISTRATOR || userDTO.getRole() == Role.SUPERADMINISTRATOR) {
                req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getContextPath() + "/admin/catalog").forward(req, resp);
            } else {
                req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getContextPath() + "/WEB-INF/pages/user/catalog/catalog.jspx").forward(req, resp);
            }
        } else {
            String errorMsg = "Email or password is incorrect";
            req.setAttribute("error", errorMsg);
            req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getContextPath() + "/WEB-INF/pages/login.jspx").forward(req, resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }
}
```

**AdminCatalogServlet**

```
public class AdminCatalogServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<ItemDTO> itemsDTO = ItemService.getInstance().getAllItemsDTO();
        req.setAttribute("itemsDTO", itemsDTO);
        req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getContextPath() + "/WEB-INF/pages/admin/catalog/catalog.jspx").forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>StartServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>...StartServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StartServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ValidateServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>...ValidateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ValidateServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/checklogin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>AdminCatalogServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>...AdminCatalogServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AdminCatalogServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/catalog</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**Problem:** We starting from `StartServlet`, when calling `/` or `/login`. Then we enter login, password to form (method = POST) and submit to `ValidateServlet`.

After it we forward to `AdminCatalogServlet` (from prospective of Admin). Then we forward to `jsp` and our browser show to us page.
(It was 2 requests to the database) for user and for items. I think, that is all, but...then tomcat run again method `doGet()` in `StartServlet`, take user from session and forward to `ValidateServlet` to method Get. And repeated request to the database for items.

Why is this happening? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** If delete doGet() method from `ValidateServlet` or `AdminCatalogServlet`, the problem goes away, but then don't work when trying to enter to `/login` when you have logged in.

**UPDATE2:** I have traced, as advised in the comments (maybe not right). First the first request (`POST`), then the set of additional data of bootstrap. At the end there is a second request on `/validate` with the `GET` method.

**UPDATE2: To solve this problem, I have changed the `StartServlet` mapping from `/` to `""`. This means that any request to the `host:port/` will be redirected to this servlet.
The problem was due to the fact that, since the Bootstrap was connected, the browser also sent a request for favicon, css and etc. to the `host:port/favicon`. Because the `StartServlet` was mapped on `/`, then it received this request and method `GET` was started.
For more information you can read about `DefaultServlet` in Tomcat**

Comment: You probably want to track all the requests that you are actually doing in a browser (Dev Tools -> Network, and enable "Preserve Log" check box).

Comment: _"don't work when trying to enter to /login when you have logged in"_ I assume, It doesn't work because  this line in `StartServlet`  `req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getContextPath() + "/checklogin").forward(req, resp);` will pass you to `ValidateServlet.doGet`

Comment: Thanks, but I understand why it doesn't work. :) The question was asked the other.